# Allow an app to override Do Not Disturb in Oreo

Tags: applications, notifications, settings, 8.1-oreo, do-not-disturb

In Nougat, there used to be a per-app option to control which apps could override Do Not Disturb. In Oreo, I only see the Low/Medium/High/Urgent options, none of which say that they override Do Not Disturb. Is there still a way to do this for Oreo apps? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

On stock Oreo 8.0 (MiA1)

Settings → Apps and notifications  →App Info  → Choose app (not all apps have this permission)  →App Notification  → Enable override

[image]

Comment: It looks like that's only there for legacy apps, not ones that target Oreo and use its new notification channels.

Comment: Is that so? Can you quote an example app?

Comment: Chrome is one such app. I see "Allow notification dot" and then a bunch of categories, none of which contain that option.

Comment: +1. I see your point. Maybe you should ask a separate question( using this as reference) to ask how it can be done for such apps. I have no answer

Comment: If your device is rooted, gravity box xposed module offers notification control that can do this